# How to save data till application un-install in android?

Tags: android, save

In Android the SharedPreference and SQLite databases are cleared once the user clear's data from Manage Applications -> Application Name -> clears Data. What if there is some information that should be persisted till the application is installed. I want to store the info till the application is installed in the device.

Is there a way to actually to do this?

Isn't there any way of storing data till the lifetime of the application? I have read that there is `getExternalFiles()` option available from 2.2 but again that is dependent on SDCard. Is there no way an app can store data permanently on Android device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@everyone-who-says-to-use-internal-storage 
That file you're talking about will be wiped if you go to Settings>Application>Manage Application>(the app)>Clear Data That is just one method to clear the data stored by your app. This method will wipe everything your app has stored since first run.

The only way to "permanently" store data is to store it on something you have control of, such as a database on your server.

EDIT: Here is simple quick and dirty test case to store and show a saved internal file. This test case is in response to @sunil comment

```
public class TestFileActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String FILENAME = "hello_file";


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        byte[] data = null;
        String collected = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput( FILENAME );

            data = new byte[fis.available()];

            while(fis.read(data) != -1) {
                collected = new String( data );
            }

            fis.close();
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById( R.id.button1 );

        b1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                putInFile();
            }
        });

        if( collected != null ) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.textView1 );

            tv.setText( collected );
        }

    }

    private void putInFile() {

        String string = "hello world!";

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal and read it. I have also checked by clearing the data from Application settings. The file do not get deleted on clearing the data. It only clears out the database and sharedpreference.

Comment: That is incorrect! Where in any of the documentation does it say that the stored data will persist after a user has cleared the application stored data via the "Clear Data" button in Application Info? Furthermore, I can post a working test case that will in fact show that anything stored **will be deleted**!!! So after you test this and find that I am correct can you please correct the downvote.

Comment: @sunil I posted an edit in response to your comment. I ran it in the emulator. I could see the file created after selecting the button and deleted after selecting "Clear Data" in Settings>Application>Manage Applications>{THEAPP}>Clear Data via DDMS.

Comment: @DDosAttack That option is not seen in all versions. Probably the newer versions have it. My solution can still work if features are introduced to handle that exceptional case when data is erased. But your solution needs a server which is not always possible. There are limitaions. But they can be overcome with good coding.

Comment: @Andrew Anderson What version does this NOT work in? The ONLY way this answer **might** not work is in the event of the user rooting their phone.

Comment: @ DDoSAttack I checked a samsung phone running 2.1. The option is simply not there. Checked another samsung running 2.3.3 and the option is there. The phones are NOT rooted.

Comment: @DDoSAttack - Sorry for actually down voting your answer. You are correct that Clear Data does clears the internal memory too. The Clear Data option is available from Android OS 2.2 and higher I guess. There should be some way to store some information till the life time of the application.

Comment: Great work here. Sorry DDoSAttack. I think I was totally wrong here with my answer. Anyway I am going to delete it. Sorry for arguing with you that my answer was correct. But still if you had found some way to store the data permanently please share it. I am in desperate need of it. +1 for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Use a file and write it to internal memory or external storage. Use encryption in case you need it to be secure.

Edit: Some versions of android have an option using which you can delete all the data that is realted to a particular application including the files. Your app must warn the user about this and you must introduce feature to take care of the situation when the file is erased

Comment: I do not want to use SD card for storing this information. 
Is there any directory specific to an application? where I can store the file and that file should not be deleted on clear data. It should be automatically deleted on uninstall of the application. Also, that file should not be accessed outside the application. The user should not be able to get to that file.

Comment: Yeah.. It is possible.!!  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

use the internal storage. The file will not be removed unless you remove it and no other application can access that file. Make it a point to use mode private when you create it.

This has worked in my application and I'm sure it will work in your app too.

Comment: That is **NOT** correct!!! Please test this yourself before declaring this to be a good answer. For an explanation and example please see my answer.

Comment: @DDosAttack I just picked up 2 phones running Android and I tested it. In 1 phone the clear data option is simply absent and in the other it is present and the data could be erased. 

So there are limitations I agree. But not in all phones

Comment: @Sunil There is a potential problem in some versions of android. You better exercise caution when you are storing in private memory

Comment: @Sunil you can target the internal memory, not the external memory card. That has the potenetial to solve the problem. Or you have to use external storage card or a remote server. 2 things that may not always be present/feasible

Comment: @Andrew Anderson That was just **one** method of clearing data. There are other ways to achieve the same result which do not involve the path I described. My point is that the OP has absolutely **NO** way locally guarantee that the data that is stored will persist until the app is uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

IF you don't want your data to be cleared in such way, you should probably not use preferences since they can be cleared by the user willingly.

If you choose sdcard as your storage medeium again you are leaving the user with their own option of deleting the contents from their storage.

So you are left with the other option which is using the Internal Memory of your application. You can follow this link for this,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Where in any of the documentation does it say that the stored data will persist after a user has cleared the application stored data via the "Clear Data" button in Application Info?

Comment: What's your problem? I am trying to explain the one who has raised this question. If you were so clear why don't you make an answer such that everyone accepts your answer.And before you that note a point that internal memory is different from preferences.

Comment: Because this is a reference site and ALL of you are providing misinformation. I did post a correct answer but because of this misinformation it was down voted. I even posted an edit proving my answer, but you still question the validity. Test my answer and you will see that what I posted is in fact correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use file system to store in internal sd card

Comment: I do not want to use SD card for storing this information. 
Is there any directory specific to an application? where I can store the file and that file should not be deleted on clear data. It should be automatically deleted on uninstall of the application. Also, that file should not be accessed outside the application. The user should not be able to get to that file.

Answer (score 0):

The internal files won't get deleted even after clearing data using "Clear Data".
I am going to use the same thing idea in my next project. Idea is --> Store the data in a file using XML format and use the same using XML parser. I hope it works for me and will provide enough hint to use it.
Here is a clue how to use internal storage -->

```
String filename = "file.txt";

FileOutputStream fos;       

fos = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_APPEND);


XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
serializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

serializer.startTag(null, "root");

for(int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
{

    serializer.startTag(null, "record");

    serializer.text(data);

    serializer.endTag(null, "record");
}
 serializer.endDocument();

 serializer.flush();

 fos.close();
```

to read back data using DOM parser:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;

    fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
    isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[fis.available()];
    isr.read(inputBuffer);
    data = new String(inputBuffer);
    isr.close();
    fis.close();

    /*
     * converting the String data to XML format
     * so that the DOM parser understand it as an XML input.
     */
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        ArrayList<XmlData> xmlDataList = new ArrayList<XmlData>();

    XmlData xmlDataObj;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
    DocumentBuilder db;
    NodeList items = null;
    Document dom;

    dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    dom = db.parse(is);
    // normalize the document
    dom.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    items = dom.getElementsByTagName("record");

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){

        Node item = items.item(i);

         arr.add(item.getNodeValue());

    }
```

Courtesy : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690185/842607